# Where on my Mac do the emulator's external data directories map to?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to figure out where the Android emulator's external storage (/sdcard/Music/ for now, but of course I want to find the other external storage locations too) maps to in my Mac's file system. I want to copy some music files over for testing a simple music playing test app.

Tried to use Device File Explorer to figure it out, but there doesn't seem to be an option for that (unlike the resource folders, which have a "reveal in Finder" right click option). Also tried the virtual device configuration options panel but didn't see it there either. Probably overlooking something obvious, so I apologize in advance. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can probably be found somewhere, but since its content can be encrypted, it would be very inconvenient to work with.

The easiest way to upload a file is to right-click on its folder in Device File Explorer and select **Upload...**

You can also do it with the `adb push <local-path> <remote-path>` command line tool if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks! Tested and uploads are persistent form run to run so this is exactly what I was after.

I stupidly assumed it would be the same paradigm as resources, but uploading mirrors the actually phone use model and makes total sense.